# Adding message handler on the fly

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have four message handlers - MyHandler, MyHandler1, MyHandler2 and MyOtherHandler. I have MyHandler and MyOtherHandler added to the handlers collection, but not MyHandler1 or MyHandler2.

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyHandler());
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyOtherHandler());
```

I want MyHandler1 or MyHandler2 to be added to the pipeline on the fly by MyHandler, depending on some condition. I know that MyHandler1 and 2 can be added to the config.MessageHandlers collection and do nothing when their turn comes, when 'some' condition does not apply but that is not what I want. Let's say I have about 100 such handlers and I don't want all of them to run in the pipeline but only when MyHandler thinks it is appropriate.

I cannot manually insert MyHandler1 into the pipeline by setting MyHandler.InnerHandler. The chain is cached globally for all requests and I cannot modify it for something related to a specific request. Here is what I did.

I created a base handler that increases the visibility of SendAsync.

```
public abstract class MyBaseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> WrapperSendAsync(
                                    HttpRequestMessage request,
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return this.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I derived MyHandler1 and 2 from this base.

```
public class MyHandler1 : MyBaseHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                                    HttpRequestMessage request,
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Use request

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // Use response

        return response;

    }
}
```

Now, MyHandler can instantiate MyHandler1 or Myhandler2 based on the condition and sets the InnerHandler to its own InnerHandler and just call and return SendAsync through the wrapper.

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                                    HttpRequestMessage request,
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Check condition and choose MyHandler1 or MyHandler2 or just return
        // await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        var h = new MyHandler1();
        h.InnerHandler = this.InnerHandler;
        return await h.WrapperSendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // When MyHandler1 and MyHandler2 is no good, I just want
        // to do nothing and let the other handlers do their job
        // return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    }
}
```

It does work but I'm not sure if I'm breaking something by doing this. Am I overlooking something by taking this approach?

Comment: Probably you should check for couple of things like Tracing and CORS. When Tracing is enabled and when the first request is received configuration is initialized and message handlers on config are wrapped by tracing message handlers and also if CORS is enabled a cors message handler is added to the end of the list of message handlers..

Comment: Thanks, Kiran. With tracing enabled, it still works but for the handler that is dynamically added into the pipeline, System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.MessageHandlerTracer does not create a trace entry ("SendAsync"). I'm yet to test CORS though. Since you added this as comment, I cannot mark this as answer and I could only upvote your comment. I have accepted Youssef's reply as answer. You both work for MSFT after all :)

Comment: Badri, all it means is that you won't get tracing for the dynamic message handlers you're adding. That's probably fine in your case. CORS should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach looks good. I'm pretty sure it should work just fine.